# exponential model in R

Tags: r

I've been trying to fit an exponential curve to my data using ggplot and geom_smooth. I'm trying to replicate the answer to a similar problem (geom_smooth and exponential fits) but keep getting following error message:

```
> exp.model <-lm(y ~ exp(x), df)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

I don't understand the error, as there is not NA/NaN/Inf values in the dataset:

```
>df
      x         y
1  1981  3.262897
2  1990  2.570096
3  2000  7.098903
4  2001  5.428424
5  2002  6.056302
6  2003  5.593942
7  2004 10.869635
8  2005 12.425793
9  2006  5.601889
10 2007  6.498187
11 2008  6.967503
12 2009  5.358961
13 2010  3.519295
14 2011  7.137202
15 2012 19.121631
16 2013  6.479928
```

I want to use the model to plot the exponential fit:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula= (y ~ exp(x)), se=FALSE, linetype = 1)
```

Comment: exp(x) is returning Inf..

Comment: This is not what you would usually do to fit an exponential model. Can you share the model you want to fit (using mathematical notation)?

Comment: @Roland, I want to use the model to fit an exponential curve to the plot, I added the code in the question above.

Comment: So, your desired model is y = c0 + c1 * exp(x)? Usually, the exponential model is y = c0 * exp(k * t).

Comment: Look at the output of `exp(df$x)`